# Batch file will not run from task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to kick off a batch file from the task scheduler on a windows server 2008 r2.

It works fine when I run it manually from the cmd. But when I set it up as a automated task in task scheduler it is not running.

Batch file looks like (Stared out the password)
"D:\Program Files (x86)\CA\Identity Manager\Provisioning Manager\bin\etautil" -d "Prod" -u "etaadmin" -p "********" -f "Data.eta" >> Data.out

Comment: are you aware, that a batchfile started by taskmanager has a different starting directory? So it probably doesn't find it's "Data.eta"

Comment: Stephan might be right. You should try using the absolute path.

Comment: ...or at first `cd /d` to the desired path.

Comment: And if it's a batch file the first thing being invoked should be `cmd.exe /c`. And you can't redirect text to a subdirectory of Program Files, as it isn't writable for non-admin users, so your output should go to a writable directory instead.